# SQL Anywhere 10 - Quotes showing up in Output CSV

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm attempting to pull data into a CSV, however my data is showing quotes around characters pulled. How can I remove these? Also my temporary column is being separated into two different fields when it has a space

`UNLOAD
SELECT tran_num, provider_id, amount, tran_date, collections_go_to
, impacts, type, 'Store Name' AS Store
FROM transactions
TO 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\StoreName.csv' delimited by ' '`

Which the results end up looking like this:
788 SLG'    0   2009-12-21  SLG'    P'  S'  Store   Name'

With Store & Name having their own columns and the ' aren't part of the values in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UNLOAD
SELECT tran_num, provider_id, amount,
       tran_date, collections_go_to, 
       impacts, type, 'Store Name' AS Store
FROM transactions
TO 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\StoreName.csv' 
delimited by ' '
QUOTES OFF
```

That should do it.